# Static HTML/CSS/JS not getting served with NGINX config

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, node.js

So I am using my nginx with node to reverse proxy a few of my sites on a virtual host. Three of my apps have their own express servers and the sites are working as they should. However, I am now trying to serve up a static site with an index.html, a CSS file, some sass files, and a js file using some jquery. Based off the configurations that I've seen, the config that I have set up should work but I can't seem to get it to work. I have my config in my sites-available and it is linked to sites-enabled. And the folder is in the /var/www folder. I get a 404 not found when I try to pull up the site.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/template-folio/;
    index index.html;

    server_name stefano-m.com www.stefano-m.com;
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     }
}
```

I have tried a couple other variations for the root and at one point, with a different variation. I believe root /var/www/. It changed from 404 to 403(forbidden).

I am not sure what my versions are. But I believe they are all at their latest versions.

Comment: Where in the filesystem are the static files actually located?

Comment: @MichaelHampton So I tried putting them in the root(where my other sites are) at one point and that didn't work. So from what I've been researching, seems like I should be putting it in /var/www so I have put it there. I cloned it from github there. I've also tried moving it one directory deeper into the html folder

Answer (score 0):

Use the line below and put the files in that directory. I'm not sure if the trailing slash in the root command makes a difference, but I don't have one and all my Nginx configurations work.

```
root /var/www/template-folio;
```

You can also download a [static website Nginx server configuration](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/resources/aws-tutorial/config-files/nginx/sites/static-website.conf) from my [Nginx / Wordpress tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/).

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding -- location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ -- to my server block. So it's now working with the exception of me using www.domain.com. So now I need to figure out my redirect!